# Pass variable to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I'm new to javascript so my question may be basic but I need some clarifications.

A standard way to create a JSON object in javascript is  something like this

```
      var JSONObject = {
         "name": "John Johnson",
         "street": "Oslo West 16",
         "age": 33,
         "phone": "555 1234567"
        };
```

Now I want to assign a variable I get from user to JSON object (ex.)

```
 var JSONObject = {
     "name": firstName;
 }
```

where firstName is the variable extracted from user.
When I tried this it shows an error. Is there any way to pass a variable to JSON object as value?

Comment: Which error is being shown? Normally, `var JSONObject = {
         "name": firstName };` should work.

Comment: Remove the `;`, like this: `var JSONObject = { "name": firstName }`

Comment: Use JSON.parse(string) and JSON.serialize(object)

Comment: These aren't really "JSON" objects, they are just Javascript objects. JSON is a **text** format for representing values that happens (not accidentally) to be a subset of Javascript syntax.

Comment: @TrungDQ But that will remove rest of the attributes: you are creating a new object

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign a value then do like below

```
var JSONObject = {
         "name": "John Johnson",
         "street": "Oslo West 16",
         "age": 33,
         "phone": "555 1234567"
        };
var firstname = "val";
JSONObject.name = firstname;
```

this will change the `name` keys value to `val` from `John Johnson`. And as per your code a semicolon is not allowed. Doing so you will get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` error. It should be,

```
var JSONObject = {
    "name": firstName
}
```

Comment: you may also try `JSONObject['name'] = firstName;` or `JSONObject.name = firstName;`.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject is just a javascript object. Shou you can write like this.

```
JSONObject.name = firstName;
```